# Performance of Items per second vs. Seconds per item

Tags: performance, algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm which will be used to calculate a rate of production of an item.

The production could last for about an hour, and also millions of them could be produced in a second.

For storing the rate, calculating the production and reflecting it to the User Interface, which strategy between storing **Items/Time** and **Times/Item** as a rate is more optimum.

P.S. My programming language could be C, C# or Java

Comment: Use the one where zero means complete standstill and where doubling the numbers means doubling the production speed. That way, you also avoid division by zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter which way you store it. That is, imagine you process 100 items in 20 seconds. So items per time is 100/20, or 5 items per second. Time per item is 20/100, or 1 item every 0.2 seconds.

So let's say you store it as items per time, or 5. Then time per item is 1/5, or 0.2 seconds. And if you store it as time per item (0.20), then items per time is 1/0.20, or 5 items per second.

If the value stored is 0, then both items per time and time per item are 0.

But to tell the truth, I'd store the number of items *and* the elapsed time, and do the calculation as required. The reason for that is because very often when you want to know the rate you also want to know the actual numbers of items and the elapsed time. And you're only talking a few extra bytes of memory anyway.

Comment: That's what i'd chosen

Answer (score 0):

Because both things are the inverse of each other there is no "optimum" way to do it, just choose which ever you beleive will be more common then in the UI layer if you detect you are below 1.0 for your rate then do `1 / your rate` to get the other number.

```
private void DisplayRate(double rate)
{
    if(rate >= 1)
    {
         lblRate.Text = String.Format("{0} Items/second", rate);
    }
    else
    {
         lblRate.Text = String.Format("{0} Seconds/item", 1.0 / rate);
    }
}
```